# My computer turns on and off repeatedly

Tags: memory, motherboard, power-supply

I left my pc open last night. When I woke up, I noticed that it's not responding (I'm not sure if it was on or off when I woke up). 
Pressed the power button - and the lights turned on but nothing appeared on the screen (fans weren't working).

I opened my computer box and disconnected the power supply from the motherboard, removed RAM cards, disconnected the hardrives and removed the small motherboard battery. Cleaned my computer from dust with a fan and reconnected everything.

The computers lights and fans were working fine but it now turns off every like, 5 seconds, nothing appear on the screen. 
I tried moving the RAM cards to different slots, removing and inserting the motherboard (GA-B75M-D3V) battery a few times... disconnected the power supply cables from the motherboard. Still that same problem. What might be the problem?

Comment: I would suggest that your power supply has failed.

Comment: i bought it like not more than 2 years ago :X

Comment: If you have another PSU, perhaps you could swap it out to test? It isn't unheard of to have a PSU go out that quickly, it could be defective. Typically defects would show up sooner depending on usage. I think checking the PSU would be the best first troubleshooting step, just as @techturtle said. If the PSU isn't the problem, it is probably a motherboard issue since the motherboard isn't functioning. You may have to swap out the motherboard.

Comment: I have a weaker power supply somewhere at home but i remember i had the same or similar problem with it 2 years ago, which is why i decided to buy a new one.

Comment: @David I connected my old 650 PSU, and it worked, i swapped back to my regular 750 PSU, and it's working now. What just happened? I still have warranty on it, should i go and replace it from where i bought it?

Comment: @techturtle See comment

Comment: @David ok i turned my pc on, i got to the windows loading screen and it shut down flat. Still the PSU?

Comment: @RickSanchez, that is the first time you identified that it got that far. It sounded like PSU since you identified "nothing appeared on the screen" You even identified "my computer doesn't turn on dude" in a comment to an answer. If you are getting to the Windows loading screen, then it is rebooting and going through the BIOS process again and getting to Windows loading, perhaps it is an OS issue. Could you try using a USB bootable OS and see if it operates okay? Be sure to make the issue clear. It is still a possible motherboard issue, but more likely OS.

Comment: Have you tried going into the BIOS?   If you can get as far as the Windows loading screen, then it makes sense to try going into the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

On BIOS Setup you should check CPU temperature. By default motherboards are configured for shutdown when a defined CPU temperature limit is reached.

You could find some reference here: [CPU Temperature required for auto-shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/129885/cpu-temperature-required-for-auto-shutdown)

Sometimes when the computer has been off for a long time this period (5 seconds) tends to be longer.

This two videos could give you some guidance in this issue:

- [How to monitor CPU temperature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av476ATXgTg)
- [Ideal CPU Temperature Ranges](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIq7TSszPFo)

Comment: my computer doesn't turn on dude.

Comment: "it now turns off every like, 5 seconds" to turn off it has to be on first. When you say it doesn't turns on you mean doesn't shows nothing on screen or doesn't turns on at all?